# How to react on listitem double click and to add context menu for each listitem?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I have `listbox` element in my xul. [`listitem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/listitem) elements are added there dynamically.

How can I:

1. react on double click on each `listitem`?
2. implement context menu for each `listitem`?

During `listitem`s creation, I know unique id (numeric) of each record added there. Ideally when double click function is called and when context menu item is chosen, I should get this id (and it shouldn't be visible to the user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events bubble which means that you can register your event handler on the `<listbox>` element. `event.target` allows you to find the `<listitem>` element:

```js
listbox.addEventListener("dblclick", function(event)
{
  var target = event.target;
  while (target && target.localName != "listitem")
    target = target.parentNode;
  if (!target)
    return;   // Event target isn't a list item

  alert(target.getAttribute("recordId"));
}, false);
```

This assumes that you've added `recordId` attributes to your list items before adding them to the list.

Things work similarly with context menus (you add a `context="..."` attribute to the `<listbox>`), with the difference that context menus are usually initialized in the menu's `popupshowing` event. The target of this event is the context menu itself so it doesn't help you find the list item. However, there is a [`menupopup.triggerNode()` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menupopup#p-triggerNode) (the modern alternative to the deprecated `document.popupNode`) that lets you do the job:

```js
menu.addEventListener("popupshowing", function(event)
{
  var target = event.target.triggerNode;
  while (target && target.localName != "listitem")
    target = target.parentNode;
  if (!target)
    return event.preventDefault(); // Don't show context menu without a list item

  alert(target.getAttribute("recordId"));
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, Wladimir. So simple. Just small correction - `listItem` in your code should be replaced with `target`.

Comment: @BGM: While I don't see how it is related to my answer here, the issue is obvious - `listbox` variable is undefined ;)

Comment: @WladimirPalant - It's only related to the answer insofaras I came here looking for the same answer (so I can't ask the same question), but I can't figure out how to apply it in my case.  I understand that `listbox` is undefined, but why?  `window.addEvenListener` works fine.

Comment: @WladimirPalant I solved my problem about getting it to fire here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127445/attach-function-to-left-click-on-listbox-item but got hung up trying to retrieve the attribute values like you've shown in your answer.  Here is my pertinent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139517/how-to-get-value-from-listbox-listitem