# Attach function to Left-Click on <listbox> item

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

In my firefox addon I have a `<listbox>`.  I want to be able to work a javascript function when I left-click on an item in the box.  The function should retrieve the item's textual value.

Now, I've tried adding this javascript, but it doesn't fire - rather, I get an error saying, *"listbox is undefined"*:

```
listbox.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var target = event.target;
    while (target && target.localName != "listitem")
    target = target.parentNode;
    if (!target)
        return;   // Event target isn't a list item
alert(target.getAttribute("value"));
}, false);
```

The xul goes something like this:

```
<listbox id="listbox1">
    <listcols /><listcol flex="1"/><listcol flex="1"/></listcols>
    <listitem><listcell class="column1" label="label1" value="value1"</listcell><listcell label="cell1"></listcell></listitem>
    <listitem><listcell class="column2" label="label2" value="value2"</listcell></listitem><listcell label="cell2"></listcell>
</listbox>
```

Now, I have two `listbox` elements in my xul.  How can I attach the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a variable named `listbox`...

```
var listbox
```

...and then you need to assign it a reference to a DOM element...

```
var listbox = document.getElementById("listbox");
```

...for example.

Don't rely on some browsers adding `id` attributes to the `window` object.

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm not getting any joy yet.  So I see you used `getElementByID` and so I did that, specifying the ID of my `listbox`, but I don't get any alert, still.  Could there be some missing correlation between the `listbox` and the `listitem`s that I am clicking on?

Comment: @BGM You seem to have `listbox1`. So just add the `1` and you may be sweet.

Comment: I get an error, still, in the console, saying "listbox1 is null" - but I defined the variable as you stated.

Comment: @BGM Are you running this code after that source is *available*?

Comment: I'm not sure - I declared the variable, like you said, just before calling the `addEventListener` - should I do that somewhere else?

Comment: Ah, I got it to fire - I placed the call in my `onload` function.  But your trick was the clencher.  Thank you!

Comment: Any clue how to get it to return the label text?

Comment: @BGM `innerText` might do it.

Comment: Oh, it's not working.  I started a new, pertinent question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139517/how-to-get-value-from-listbox-listitem