# How to get value from listbox listitem

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

In my firefox addon I have a `<listbox>`.  I want to be able to work a javascript function when I left-click on an item in the box.  The function should retrieve the item's textual value.

Now, my function *does* get called when I click on a `listitem`, as I've placed this in my event listener's onLoad call:

```
    var myListBox = document.getElementById("myListBoxID");
    myListBox.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        var target = event.target;
        while (target && target.localName != "listitem"){
            target = target.parentNode;
        }
        if (!target){
            return;   // Event target isn't a list item
        }
        alert(target);                                  //returns blank
        alert(target.id);                               //returns blank
        alert(target.getAttribute("value"));        //returns blank
        alert(target.getAttribute("text"));     //returns blank
        alert(target.getAttribute("id"));           //returns blank

        var targetid = document.getElementById(target.id);
        alert(targetid);                                //returns null
    }, false);      
},
```

The xul goes something like this:

```
<listbox id="listbox1">
    <listcols /><listcol flex="1"/><listcol flex="1"/></listcols>
    <listitem><listcell class="column1" label="label1" value="value1"</listcell><listcell label="cell1"></listcell></listitem>
    <listitem><listcell class="column2" label="label2" value="value2"</listcell></listitem><listcell label="cell2"></listcell>
</listbox>
```

However, I can't get it to display the text of the items.  As you can see above, I don't seem to have a proper handle on the `target`

I've [gotten the original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840919/how-to-react-on-listitem-double-click-and-to-add-context-menu-for-each-listitem/8847382#comment21149507_8847382) from here, and [got the `EventListener` working here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127445/attach-function-to-left-click-on-listbox-item).

**How can I get the value of the listcells?  I've tried everything!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't detect a `click` on just a `listcell`.  The closest you can go is to detect a `click` on a `listitem`.  After that, you have to drill down using code.

So, use `.childNode` on your target.  Since you have only two `listcell`s in your `listitem`, if you are trying to capture the second cell, use `childNodes[1]`.  `childNodes[0] will refer to the first cell.

```
onLoad: function(){
    var mylistbox= document.getElementById("mylistboxID");
    mylistbox.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        var target = event.target.childNodes[1];
        if (!target){
            return;   // In case there is not target
        }
        alert(target.getAttribute("label") + target.getAttribute("label"));
    }, false);      
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using this code:

```js
while (target && target.localName != "listitem"){
    target = target.parentNode;
}
```

It will go up from the actual click target looking for a `<listitem>` tag. Yet the text isn't stored in the `<listitem>` tag, it's in the `<listcell>` - so you simply should be looking for that one in the hierarchy:

```js
while (target && target.localName != "listcell"){
    target = target.parentNode;
}
alert(target.getAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: Thanks, Wladimir.  That make sense to me.  I'm still learning here.  Now, however, there is no alert at all.  The function IS firing, however, and if I comment out the `if(!target)` part, the error console tells me it is `null`.  But it looks like it is always `null` because nothing after that ever fires.

Comment: Do you have another clue for me?

Comment: Ah!  The problem is that target is `listitem` not `listcell`.

Comment: If I put an alert before the last bracket of the `while`, I see: **listitem, listbox, vbox, prefpane, window**  - I need to get to the child of the target, not the parent.  How do I do that?